# Faster way to get virtual allocation addresses

Tags: delphi, virtual-memory

I would like to process (save) the virtual memory blocks allocated to the current process. Here is the code I am using:

```
program Project38;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows;

procedure DoProcess(aStart: Pointer; aSize: Cardinal);
begin
  // process it
end;

procedure ProcessVirtualMemory;
var
  addr: Pointer;
  i: Integer;
  p: Pointer;
  systemInfo: SYSTEM_INFO;
  startAddress, stopAddress: Pointer;
  size: size_t;
  memInfo: MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
begin
  GetSystemInfo(systemInfo);
  startAddress := systemInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
  stopAddress := systemInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;

  addr := startAddress;

  while NativeUInt(addr) < NativeUInt(stopAddress) do begin
    size:= VirtualQuery(Pointer(addr), memInfo, SizeOf(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));
    if (size = SizeOf(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)) and
       (memInfo.State = MEM_COMMIT) and
       (memInfo.Type_9 = MEM_PRIVATE) and
       (memInfo.RegionSize > 0) and
       (memInfo.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE) then
    begin
      DoProcess(memInfo.BaseAddress, memInfo.RegionSize);
      addr := Pointer(NativeUInt(addr) + memInfo.RegionSize);
    end
    else
      addr := Pointer(NativeUInt(addr) + systemInfo.dwPageSize);
  end;
end;

begin
  ProcessVirtualMemory;
end.
```

This code is run with a huge application and collecting this information without processing is 10-12 seconds. Is there a faster way of getting the addresses of the virtual memory blocks?

Comment: How do you imagine speeding this up? How else could it be implemented?

Comment: Well that is the question. Maybe it is possible to ask the windows the list of allocated pages instead of calling VirtualQuery for each memory page.

Comment: Nope, this is the only way to do what you want. However, you are doing it wrongly, as I explain below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program does contain a mistake. In case the memory block does not match your search criteria, you only increment by the page size rather than the region size. Your loop should really look like this:

```
while NativeUInt(addr) < NativeUInt(stopAddress) do begin
  size := VirtualQuery(Pointer(addr), memInfo, SizeOf(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION));

  if size = 0 then begin
    // handle error
    break
  end;

  if (size = SizeOf(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)) and
     (memInfo.State = MEM_COMMIT) and
     (memInfo.Type_9 = MEM_PRIVATE) and
     (memInfo.RegionSize > 0) and
     (memInfo.Protect = PAGE_READWRITE) then begin
    DoProcess(memInfo.BaseAddress, memInfo.RegionSize);
  end;

  addr := Pointer(NativeUInt(addr) + memInfo.RegionSize);
end;
```

The problem with your version is that when there are gaps in the virtual address space, your code walks over them one page at a time, rather than skipping the entire region.

Even without that change, I don't believe that enumeration was the bottleneck. I made the following alteration to your original program, to report the time taken:

```
var
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;

begin
  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  ProcessVirtualMemory;
  Writeln(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

  Readln;
end.
```

On my machine, for a 32 bit release build, this reported around 500ms.

Then I allocated some memory:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;

begin
  for i := 1 to 100000 do begin
    HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap, 0, Random(100000));
  end;

  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  ProcessVirtualMemory;
  Writeln(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

  Readln;
end.
```

No matter what I did, playing around with the constants, the program still reports around 500ms. If you fix the non-matching increment code as described at the start of this answer then the times come down to around 100ms.

Of course, for a 64 bit process, it's a little different. The defect in your code means that the program effectively gets stuck walking the huge 64 bit address space one page at a time, calling `VirtualQuery` for each page in the address space. I never even waited for that process to finish.

My conclusion therefore is that the main bottleneck in your program is not the code that your present, the code that finds the virtual memory blocks. That is the code inside `DoProcess`, the code that you have that we don't. So even when you fix the defect I described at the start, you will still spend significant time in that function. You should expect the virtual memory space enumeration to take in the region of 100ms.